# Use IF or Polymorphism?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, design-patterns, polymorphism

I have a question about Java. I've been working with Java for less than a year, and I'm starting to have interesting doubts about design patterns:

For example, I want to improve my code with Object-Oriented (OO) principles to make it cleaner, but it raised a question: won't I increase the processing time?

In the code below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class EscritorioContabilidade {
    
    //metodo para recuperar a informacao salarial utilizando os IF´s da pior maneira....rsrsr
    public double getSalarioFuncionario(String tipoFuncionario){
        double salario = -1;
        if("gerente".equals(tipoFuncionario)){
            salario = 1000;
        }
        else if("balconista".equals(tipoFuncionario)){
            salario = 900;
        }
        else if("faixineiro".equals(tipoFuncionario)){
            salario = 550;
        }
        return salario;
    }
    
    //metodo para recuperar a informacao salarial utilizando os IF´s. Nao melhoramos muito
    public double getSalarioFuncionario(Object funcionario){
        double salario = -1;
        if(funcionario instanceof Gerente){
            salario = 1000;
        }
        else if(funcionario instanceof Balconista){
            salario = 900;
        }
        else if(funcionario instanceof Faixineiro){
            salario = 550;
        }
        return salario;
    }
    
    //metodo para recuperar a informacao salarial utilizando polimorfismo. Agora sim!
    public double getSalarioFuncionario(Funcionario funcionario){
        return funcionario.informarSalario();
    }
    
    public static void main(String [] asdf){
        EscritorioContabilidade escritorioContabilidade = new EscritorioContabilidade();
        double folhaPagamento = 0;
        
        List<Funcionario> listaFuncionario = new ArrayList<Funcionario>();
        
        //adicionando os funcionarios 
        listaFuncionar
```

```
io.add(new Gerente());
        listaFuncionario.add(new Balconista());
        listaFuncionario.add(new Faixineiro());
        
        //usando o polimorfismo para determinar a folha de pagamento
        for (Funcionario funcionario : listaFuncionario) {
            folhaPagamento += escritorioContabilidade.getSalarioFuncionario(funcionario);
        }
        System.out.println("folha de pagamento: "+folhaPagamento);
        
        //agora vamos usar um dos metodos que utilizam os IFs e voces podem ver a clareza em ambos os trechos de codigo
        folhaPagamento = 0;
        folhaPagamento +=  escritorioContabilidade.getSalarioFuncionario("gerente");
        folhaPagamento +=  escritorioContabilidade.getSalarioFuncionario("balconista");
        folhaPagamento +=  escritorioContabilidade.getSalarioFuncionario("faixineiro");
        
        System.out.println("folha de pagamento: "+folhaPagamento);
    }
}


public abstract class Funcionario {
    public abstract double informarSalario();
}


public class Gerente extends Funcionario {

    @Override
    public double informarSalario() {
        return 1000;
    }

}

class Balconista extends Funcionario{

    @Override
    public double informarSalario() {
        return 900;
    }
    
}

class Faixineiro extends Funcionario{

    @Override
    public double informarSalario() {
        return 550;
    }
    
}
```

In this code, if I use polymorphism, my code certainly becomes more elegant. However, if I use if statements, wouldn't it have better performance because it doesn't create memory pointers and such?

I hope to clarify a question about Java and design patterns.

Comment: Have you actually profiled the different code to see how much effect we're talking about (if any)? Donald Knuth, one of the most famous researchers and educators on programming algorithm's once said, "*The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.*".

Comment: For more on this, please read: [Why Premature Optimization Is the Root of All Evil](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)

Comment: Examples of things that hurt efficiency in the real world are network calls, unindexed queries, and memory leaks. What youre describing is not a valid issue, youre making your code unreadable for no good reason.

Comment: @NathanHughes: and add to your list of loss of efficiency risks: time spent debugging errors, especially those due to high cyclomatic complexity, something that clean code, with low coupling and high cohesion, is supposed to reduce.

Comment: I have to very strongly echo Hovercraft's comments, as well as the answer by Bohemian below.  This kind of guessing at performance, especially where the trade-off is to not use best practice in design (encapsulation, single responsibility, open/close principles, dependency injection, and other fundamentals of design), is almost always a terrible idea.  Make the code correct first, especially including good design, then test for performance and actually measure what needs improving.

Answer (score 9):

The "memory and performance" differences are negligible, approaching zero.

You're always better to have several classes that each have constant behaviour than one "Swiss army knife" class that has variable behaviour.

Your "typed" solution is easier to read, understand, test and extend - *that's* the most important aspect to consider.

Comment: The difference in time between using if tests and polymorphism is measured in nanoseconds.   The time it takes to find and fix a bug in production code is measured in hours.  CPU time is cents per hour.  Programmer time is $50 per hour. Do the maths.

Answer (score 2):

When optimizing code first analyze the code and determine where the bottleneck is, then address the bottleneck. Optimizing anything else is a waste of time.

Most applications have issues like slow network calls or unindexed queries, etc, that will be slowing things down. If virtual method lookups really are your bottleneck, then congratulations, you have a super fast program. At some point optimizing won't be cost effective and won't yield significant benefits, it is overwhelmingly likely you will hit that point way before virtual methods become an issue.  Part of optimization is knowing when to quit.

What we try to optimize for in real life is developer time, where we try to write code that is clear and not confusing. The benefit of polymorphism is that the flow of the program doesnt have to care about details of subclasses, which stay out of the way, unlike your if-tests which are mixed into the logic flow. Think of what a hassle it would be to add another subclass in the if-test version, how you would have to search for all the if checks and add another case.

2 main lessons:

- Measure before performance tuning so you can make an informed decision about whether it's worthwhile, don't make assumptions.
- Optimize for your time, it is a lot more costly than a few cpu cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is a non-functional requirement. First of all, it should be "enough" for business. If the performance is more than enough, you are probably do over engineering. This is a point number one.

Point number two:
Carl Wiegers in his book "Software Requirements" shows a table how non-functional requirements relates to each other. [image]

Let's see how relates modifiability(let's say clean code in this case) and performance to other types of requirements.

Modifiability mostly relates positive, and performance relates negative. So, improving modifiability(using polymorphism over conditional for example) is better for system in common case.

The last trick: if your system is easy to modify, then you can always tune performance or any other requirement and vice versa.